# Mouse pointer leaves trail

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, monitors

I've just started using Linux on my laptop, and I am facing some difficulties working with an external monitor. At first, I tried connecting with HDMI, but then the resolution was limited. Also the mouse pointer leaves a kind of trail when moving it, which then disappears within a few seconds after stopping movement of the mouse. I tried connecting with a DP cable, and then I get the full resolution of my external monitor, but the mouse pointer is still an issue.

Strangely, if I open display settings (and even minimize it), it is no longer an issue and the mouse pointer works fine.  If I close it (or go into some other settings), the problem reappears.

What could cause this?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and my graphics card is Nvidia GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M].

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Linux has not yet reached point where it could be used with GUI normally, especially with nVidia cards... I had the same issue a time ago and I've set 
`CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling` in `/etc/environment` and initially worked fine. Some updates after problem re-appeared.
You can try to add `evdi` to `/etc/modules` and then `options evdi initial_device_count=2` to `/etc/modprobe.d/evdi.conf`
On my system this solved the issue... If you are lucky enough, it will help on your system as well... Good luck!

Comment: Actually, the problem got resolved when i changed from HDMI to DP. And then, later, when I tried HDMI, it worked. Probably a driver update or something. Tried using 2 remote monitors (one HDMI, one DP), but then when the computer slept one of the monitors became unresponsive. But that's a different story :p At least I have one working external monitor at the time, think I'll have stick with that.